# Failed to connect to Mongolab from Heroku

Tags: heroku

I am getting this error below when deploying to heroku. I have read through the documentation but I don't know what to do about it:

```
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

And yes I did run heroku addons:create mongolab -a and have the config vars on the heroku website. Here's my server file:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var morgan = require("morgan")
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('dotenv').config()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8081
const rateRoutes = require('./routes/rateRouter')
const path = require("path")

app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")))


//connect to mongolab
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/rate', { useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then(()=>console.log('Successfully connected to mongoDB'))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))

app.use('/last', rateRoutes)
app.use('/', rateRoutes)

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log("starting")
})
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem at line of connection, are you sure that this link:
mongodb://localhost:27017/rate
is coming from mongolab ??
this is local database and heroku doesn't have access to it, and i think link provided from mongolab to connect database globally will be different.